# Scrollbar and Smooth Scrolling Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Please check this page (for an example)

```
http://www.christinamichael.in/create-a-powerful-human-disintegration-effect-in-photoshop
```

I want to know how can i have such this ?

I want something to be supported in firefox and chrome .

Comment: Wow, that is really annoying. I wouldn't recommend you do this. My Chrome seems to have some issues with it (scroll stuttering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the smooth scrolling with use of ANCHOR tag.
Below results.

---

$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
var target = $(this.hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
if (target.length) {
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1000);
return false;
}
}
});
});